# cannot use values of session variables in another page

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I created a `session` in my `index page` AKA `login page`, when I'm trying to use that value in select query in another page it does not work can any one help me[image]

[image]

```
    <?php 
session_start();

$connection = mysql_connect('localhost','root','root') or die ("Couldn't connect to server.");  
$db = mysql_select_db('test', $connection) or die ("Couldn't select database.");  


$data ="select user_id,first_name,last_name,father_name,address,pincode,dob,phone from acc where user_id='" .$_SESSION['userSession']. "'"; 
  $query = mysql_query($data) or die("Couldn't execute query. ". mysql_error()); 
  $data2 = mysql_fetch_array($query); 

?> 

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html> 
<head> 
      <title></title> 
 </head> 

<body> 

<!-- form to display record from database --> 
<center>
<form name="form" method="POST" action="abcd2.php"> 
  first Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo  $data2 ['first_name']?>"/> <br> 
 last Name : <input type="text" name="lastname" value="<?php echo  $data2 ['last_name']?>"/> <br>
 father Name: <input type="text" name="fathername" value="<?php echo  $data2 ['father_name']?>"/> <br> 
 address: <input type="text" name="address" value="<?php echo  $data2 ['address']?>"/> <br> 
 pincode: <input type="text" name="pincode" value="<?php echo  $data2 ['pincode']?>"/> <br> 
  DOB: <input type="text" name="dob" value="<?php echo  $data2 ['dob']?>"/><br>
  phone: <input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo  $data2 ['phone']?>"/> <br> 
      <input type="submit"  value="submit"> 
</form> 
</center>
</body> 

</html>
```

Comment: Please add source code not image.

Comment: Did you called ``session_start()`` at the top of your file?

Comment: Make sure you started the session on the page/file you want to use it by doing. `session_start();`

Comment: use session_start() first line of your code....

Comment: That's not even remotely valid mysql, you should start with the manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to start the session !

Use `session_start()` before assigning anything to the `$_SESSION` super global and on the other page type `session_start` before retrieving anything so you can resume the session

hope you got it

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```
session_start();
```

in order to fetch the value of session variable

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: Where are you fecthing the ** $_SESSION['userSession'] **?